# Difference in stats on the audit and google speed test

Tags: google-pagespeed, lighthouse

I've been looking to improve our website speed. I've been using the lighthouse audits and google speed insights. I've taken a screenshot to show the differences. Am I doing something wrong or is this a common issue?
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply because your computer is nearer to your server than Google's. Using their website ping your server from theirs (Silicon Valley, California - Google HQ) to your server.

I use the Inspector Audits all the time, it's more accurate.

I've ran some test to prove this out. I'm in New York and the server of my website is in New York, I got a score of 97 (pagespeed was 77)

Then I've tried from Australia to my New York server and the score in the inspector was 1. So depending on your locations, the score will change a lot because Google remove big amount of points on latency.

TL;DR : Use the inspector for more accurate results base on your location instead of using the website which is based on their location.